# Tensorflow throws 'Incompatible shapes' error in Lambda layer when batch_size > 1

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras, embedding

I have a simple CNN with two inputs for text processing (code below). One input for tokens another one for weights. Both inputs are sequences of the same `MAX_LENGTH`. After passing tokens through embedding layer I'd like to multiply those embeddings by corresponding weights. So I defined new Lambda layer and function **mult** for this purpose.

**Actual behaviour**

When I try model fitting with only input in a `batch_size==1` it works. But if `batch_size > 1` it shows

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes
```

**Expected behaviour**

Model fits correctly with batches of any size.

**Exception**

Here is an example of exception when running fit with `batch_size=256`, `MAX_LENGTH=30`, `EMB_SIZE=300`:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [256,30,300] vs. [30,256] [[{{node lambda_41/mul}}]]
```

Does it imply **imp_w** tensor shape equal `[30,256]`? Shouldn't it be equal `[256,30]` instead?

Finally the question is what's wrong with my network configuration? Thx!

```py
def mult(tensors):
    # print(tensors[0].shape, tensors[1].shape)
    return np.multiply(tensors[0], K.transpose(tensors[1]))

def TextSentCNN(n_filters, filter_sizes):
    inp_t = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,))
    inp_w = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,))

    x = Embedding(MAX_FEATURES, EMB_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp_t)    
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(mult, output_shape=(MAX_LENGTH, EMB_SIZE,))([x, inp_w])
    x = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(x)
    x = Reshape((MAX_LENGTH, EMB_SIZE, 1))(x)    

    pools = []
    for filter_size in filter_sizes:
        conv = Conv2D(n_filters, kernel_size=(filter_size, EMB_SIZE), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')(x)
        pool = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(MAX_LENGTH - filter_size + 1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(conv)
        pools.append(pool)

    x = Concatenate(axis=1)(pools)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dropout(.5)(x)
    out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[inp_t, inp_w], outputs=out)
    model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the lambda layer, your tensor `x` has shape `(batch_size, MAX_LENGTH, EMB_SIZE)` and `inp_w` has shape `(batch_size, MAX_LENGTH)`. Since you are taking the transpose of `inp_w` inside your custom `mult` function, you end up with the shapes mentioned in the error message, which are incompatible.

Another problem with your code is that you are trying to use a numpy function inside a lambda layer. You should only use Keras backend functions. The following code should work instead:

```py
def mult(tensors):
    x = tensors[0] # shape (bs, len, dim)
    weights = K.expand_dims(tensors[1], -1) # shape (bs, len, 1)
    return weights * x # pointwise multiplication
```